# which is the right grammatical usage?

Tags: prepositions

> A thief does not ______ the door.

Is the correct expression to fill the gap 'knock **at**' or 'knock **on**'?

Comment: People are often challenged to explain the reason/s behind their downvotes. I challenge the phantom upvoter here to explain their reasoning.

Comment: maybe because their question isn't relevant